# Integration of a function containing inverse trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, trigonometry, inverse, indefinite-integrals

**Q.** $$\int \sin\left\{2\tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{3-x}{3+x}}\right)\right\}dx$$

$\implies$ $$\int \sin\left\{\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{2\left(\sqrt{\frac{3-x}{3+x}}\right)}{1+\left(\sqrt{\frac{3-x}{3+x}}\right)^2}\right)\right\}dx$$

$\implies$ $$\int \:\frac{\left(\sqrt{3^2-x^2}\right)}{3}dx$$
$\implies$ANSWER $=$$$\frac{1}{3}\left(\left[\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{3^2-x^2}\right]+\left[\frac{9}{2}\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\right]\right)=\left(\left[\frac{x}{6}\sqrt{3^2-x^2}\right]+\left[\frac{3}{2}\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\right]\right)$$

Am I right?

Comment: This looks fine (with +C at the end).

Answer (score 2):

Set $u=\arctan\sqrt{\dfrac{3-x}{3+x}}$. Then
$$
\sqrt{\dfrac{3-x}{3+x}}=\tan u
$$
and
$$
\dfrac{3-x}{3+x}=\tan^2u
$$
and, with straighforward computations,
$$
x=3\cos2u
$$
so
$$
dx=-6\sin2u\,du
$$
Thus your integral becomes
$$
\int-6\sin^{2}2u\,du
$$
that you should be able to carry over.

Comment: When you substitute, I think you get $\int -6\sin^{2}2u du$.

Comment: @user84413 Yes, you're right. Thanks.